# GNU build system question

Tags: c, linker

How to find the library, which contains the definition of particular function? I am getting linker error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `nm` command-line tool to list exported symbols in binaries:

```
~/src> cat nm-test.c

static int plus_four(int x)
{
        return x + 4;
}

int sum_plus_four(int a, int b)
{
        return plus_four(a + b);
}

int product_plus_four(int a, int b)
{
        return plus_four(a * b);
}
~/src> gcc -c nm-test.c
~/src> nm ./nm-test.o
00000000 t plus_four
00000023 T product_plus_four
0000000b T sum_plus_four
```

According to [the manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html), 't' means that the symbol is in the code (text) segment, and uppercase means it's public.

If you have a symbol that you're looking for, you can use `nm` to make the symbols exported by a library accessible to e.g. grep:

```
$ find -name lib*.a /example/library/path | xargs nm | grep -E "T $SYMBOL_TO_FIND"
```

This command-line is an untested sketch, but it should show the concept.

Comment: Does that not find the function names given the library, rather than the library given the function name?

Comment: @Pete: True, but since it exports the information, it can be used to grep over library files.

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of the C standard API then just run `man`, it should clearly state where the function is defined.

Comment: And if it's not, the library documentation presumably states how to link to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the library in non-programmatical way, you might find [LSB Navigator](http://dev.linuxfoundation.org/navigator/) useful.  Enter the function into the search box, and check the library in the line with green "status".

[image]
<sub>(source: [coldattic.info](http://coldattic.info/pic/165509391387.png))</sub>

This will be the "conventional" library that contains the function (in the example depicted above, `librt` is the correct library for `mq_unlink`, so you link with `-lrt`).  Just link with that library, and it will work on virtually all Linux systems.

<sub>Note: I was one of the developers of the tool I recommend.</sub>